# Why does copying a string from Outlook to Excel open a new instance of Excel for each email?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've written this script to search an Outlook folder containing a series of emails with a certain string of information in the email body to copy into an Excel file.

When I first created and ran the script there weren't any problems, this is the second time I'm running it and it's excruciatingly slow and froze up my computer. I noticed it seems to be opening a new instance of Excel for each email.

I'm confused because it ran without error the first time, no changes to the script and second time running it, well I couldn't let it finish because the computer froze. Is there any way to not open a new instance for every email?

I'm not interested in revamping the entire code, but if we can make it more efficient in a simple way, count me in.

To be clear, this is run from Outlook as a rule and is run once a week.

```
 Sub CopyToExcel(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)
 Dim xlApp As Object
 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Dim xlWB As Object
 Dim xlSheet As Object
 Dim xlOpenWB As Object
 Dim vText As Variant
 Dim sText As String
 Dim rCount As Long
 Dim bXStarted As Boolean
 Dim enviro As String
 Dim strPath As String
 Dim Reg1 As RegExp
 Dim M1 As MatchCollection
 Dim M As Match
 Dim xlUp As Long
 Dim FileName As String
 xlUp = -4162

FileName = "\Desktop\newhires" & Format(Date, "yyyyMMDD") & ".xlsx"

enviro = (Environ("USERPROFILE"))

'the path of the workbook VB function, don't change
 strPath = enviro & FileName

 'Add the workbook to input the data
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
     xlWB.SaveAs (strPath)

     Set xlOpenWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlOpenWB.Sheets("newhires")
  'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
     rCount = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

     rCount = rCount + 1

'sText is content of the email
    sText = olItem.Body

    Set Reg1 = New RegExp

    ' \s* = invisible spaces
    ' \d* = match digits
    ' \w* = match alphanumeric

    With Reg1
        .pattern = "(Employee Number\s*[:]\s*(\d*))"
    End With
    If Reg1.test(sText) Then

        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(sText)
        For Each M In M1
           vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
        Next
    End If

    xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = vText
    vText.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
    xlOpenWB.Close 1

  xlApp.Quit
  Set Reg1 = Nothing
  Set xlApp = Nothing
  Set xlWB = Nothing
  Set xlSheet = Nothing
  Set xlOpenWB = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: your problem is that whatever method is calling this one is sending in the mail item and you create the excel object in this method.  You should create it in the calling method and pass it as a param to this one that way you don't create a new instance every time this is called.

Comment: @Sorceri where would be the quickest way for me to learn about the calling method, passing as a parameter, etc. Also, the use of this one and that way, this is my first VB script so more explanation would be helpful. I need it to pass each time I run this script, since this will be ran once a week and I need it to create a new excel file each time. I was trying to reuse the variable strPath, which is why I included it where I did and this is causing the problem? So, I need to create the excel file in the calling method and then pass it where?

Comment: You need to open the visual basic editor on the developer tab and in the module that has this code and look for what is calling it CopyToExcel(mailItem) and post that code.

Comment: @Sorceri that is the first line of the code. I pasted the entire script here, didn't leave anything out.

Comment: Updated answer to show you GetObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you are running this as a rule with a script as the action. Use GetObject to get the current instance and if an error occurs create one.  May also want to remove the quit call as that is exiting out of Excel.

```
Sub CopyToExcel(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)
 On Error Resume Next
 Dim xlApp as Object
 Dim xlWB As Object
 Dim xlSheet As Object
 Dim xlOpenWB As Object
 Dim vText As Variant
 Dim sText As String
 Dim rCount As Long
 Dim bXStarted As Boolean
 Dim enviro As String
 Dim strPath As String
 Dim Reg1 As RegExp
 Dim M1 As MatchCollection
 Dim M As Match
 Dim xlUp As Long
 Dim FileName As String
 xlUp = -4162
'try and get the current running object
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'no object was found so create one
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Err.Clear
End If
FileName = "\Desktop\newhires" & Format(Date, "yyyyMMDD") & ".xlsx"

enviro = (Environ("USERPROFILE"))

'the path of the workbook VB function, don't change
 strPath = enviro & FileName

 'Add the workbook to input the data
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
     xlWB.SaveAs (strPath)

     Set xlOpenWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlOpenWB.Sheets("newhires")
  'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
     rCount = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

     rCount = rCount + 1

'sText is content of the email
    sText = olItem.Body

    Set Reg1 = New RegExp

    ' \s* = invisible spaces
    ' \d* = match digits
    ' \w* = match alphanumeric

    With Reg1
        .Pattern = "(Employee Number\s*[:]\s*(\d*))"
    End With
    If Reg1.test(sText) Then

        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(sText)
        For Each M In M1
           vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
        Next
    End If

    xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = vText
    vText.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
    xlOpenWB.Close 1
  'removed xlApp.Quit
  xlApp = Nothing
  Set Reg1 = Nothing
  Set xlWB = Nothing
  Set xlSheet = Nothing
  Set xlOpenWB = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation & example. So this is running & it asks me for EVERY email "this file already exists do you want to overwrite it..." instead of replacing the file, I just need it to open the existing one (the one it creates) and append the next string to it.

Comment: replace the SaveAs with Save since it is an existing document.  If it resolved the issue mark is as answer as well.

Comment: It works, but doesn't solve the problem of an incredibly slow task. It's no longer opening a new instance (and keeping it open) but instead it is opening and closing a new excel instance every time thus causing the process to be even slower. Because I'm thinking in Python, I feel like there should be an else line, If open already exists, open it, leave it open and copy the string to the file then when done end the process.

Comment: Did you remove the xlApp.Quit call?

Comment: Ah, yes I removed the xlApp.Quit call but I had instead of xlApp = Nothing as Set xlApp = Nothing. It's no longer closing each time, still is slower than preferred (5min to process 131 emails) but now it doesn't kill the excel process when finished so I have to manually kill it.